# Intersection of two circles with same radii

Tags: geometry

It is said that two circles can have at most,  two intersection points. Does the same hold for two circles that have the same radii?

Comment: Your problem is overlapping two circles and have infinity intersection points?

Comment: well, not if they are the same circle

Comment: So same circles have infinite intersection points if they overlap?

Comment: I assume that the statement concerns two *different* circles.

Answer (score 0):

First if two circles have two different radius (different than 0) then for the maximum case they can only intersect at two points but if they have the same radius then the maximum intersecting points will be infinite and whole the circle and not less then whole circle.

Answer (score 0):

If two equal disks have coinciding centers, then their boundary circles touch everywhere.

When centers are not same then there are two intersection points.

When the disks... and so their boundary circles... touch externally, then the two points coincide, making for a tangent and a double root in solution of their equations.

Answer (score -1):

Two circle, if truly the intersect can only have $2$ intersection points

This statement is not a function of its radius, so even if they have same or different radius...... They'll still always have $2$ intersection points

Infinite intersection points is when the circles occupy the same space

Three circles, if truly they all intersect has $6$ intersection points

Four circles have $12$ intersection points

$n$ circles have $n(n-1)$ intersection points

The cause of this is the geometry of circle, two curve creates a loop.... Which has $2$ junctions

Comment: I would assume the question here was about *real* intersection points.

Comment: What about sharing a common point? Three circles can have $5$ intersection points as well.